# Admin interface for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, django-orm, formalchemy

I've been developing a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) app, however I've recently changed the overall architecture plan. I no longer need a web-framework, just a simple Python script, so I'm changing from using the Django ORM to using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to create and manage the database.

Previously I was using the Django Admin interface to review things that users had posted (which get added to the database), for the purposes of moderating them.

I still need a way of moderating user added content via a website. I think there are two options:

- Build an admin web interface myself, from scratch :(
- Use an existing library, that makes creating an admin interface easier (for a database created with SQLAlchemy).

I've started looking into [FormAlchemy](http://docs.formalchemy.org/). If you've got experience with FormAlchemy: is it possible to create an admin interface with it, and is a particular framework that is preferable to build it with?

Otherwise, do you know of any good solutions to the SQLAlchemy admin interface problem?

Comment: I find [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to be the simplest framework for web apps. Take a look at it.

Comment: Cool, I've used Flask in the past, probably the most lightweight Python framework atm.

Comment: Have you looked at its [SQLAlchemy extension](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/)? It's pretty awesome.

Comment: I'm thinking Flask is the way to go for this very simple admin interface (combined with Twitter Bootstrap for all CSS needs) - hopefully making it won't be too painless.

Comment: I've made somewhat-complex admin interfaces with Flask and they were really easy to setup. For once I actually spent more time designing the website than coding the backend.

Comment: @Blender, thank you for the gift of hope. Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [Flask-Admin](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/). Right now it has about 70% of Django features, some really great features, that Django doesn't support and it extremely flexible as Flask

Comment: Unfortunately, Flask-Admin appears to be a dead project.  (for now)  It has 381 issues, 64 PRs, and no activity for a year.  Also, I got an error simply by following the examples on the first page - triggered by: `from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView`.  It's a shame, because I dislike Django Admin...

Comment: It's the future. It's 2023. And I have good news - it does not appear to be dead! Wahoo!

Answer (score 4):

You can also check fa.bootstrap - twitter bootstrap integration for pyramid_formalchemy:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fa.bootstrap

With pyramid_formalchemy it is now much easier to get admin panel in non django-app.

Answer (score 3):

[Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) is really great for this, but its a desktop app.

[Restin](http://code.google.com/p/restin/) is another option if you are using [elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki) (which you should be, to be honest).

Comment: Camelot doesn't look like it's maintained anymore

Answer (score 2):

There wasn't one when I looked, either. But I did start developing one myself. I have a generic data editor working now, although not as far along as the Django one. You're welcome to fork it.

Mostly found in these files:

http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/webhelpers.py
http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/webservice.py

But it does depend on the [pycopia](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/) web application framework as well. It's a basic server-side interface now, but I've been converting it to a JSON/XHR type RPC interactive interface.

I actually use it, even though it's not complete.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for making your work publicly available, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

there is another option called "sqladmin" - https://github.com/aminalaee/sqladmin

docs: https://aminalaee.dev/sqladmin/

Comment: As of 2023-Jan-12, your suggestion is the only one that exists and is active.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new (WIP) package `django-sqlalchemy`:

https://github.com/auvipy/django-sqlalchemy